# Replace basic image with a different image on certain dates. Possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need some help with the following; I have a private start page for my browsers. This page is also used by family and displays news, weather, etc.

Now to make it a bit nicer, I want the standard logo to be replaced by a image of Santa and a birthday cake on several birthdays. How do I achieve this and what's the best solution to use for this? PHP, jQuery or something else?

For example during Christmas the standard logo (logo.png) should be replaced with santa1.png or santa2.png.

On Eastern the standard logo (logo.png) should be replaced by bunny1.png, bunny2.png or easteregg.png
And so on for various other days... You get the idea.

Unfortunately I don't have any programming skills. So if anyone could write up a small and easy to use code snippet, I would be very happy.

Thank you in advance.

//edit

Thank you for the replies and yes I do not have any skills in regards to programming, however I did start a search in regards to Javascript changing images on certain dates and I found the following:

```
        <script language="javascript">
         var pic='';
         mytime=new Date();
         mymonth=mytime.getMonth()+1;
         mydate=mytime.getDate();
         if (mymonth==7 && mydate==15){pic="<img src=/images/14.png width=300 height=300>";
         }
         else if (mymonth==7 && mydate==17){pic="<img src=/images/19.png width=300 height=300>";
         }
         else if (mymonth==7 && mydate==18){pic="<img src=/images/13.png width=300 height=300>";
         }
         else {
         pic="<img src=../img/logo.png width=480 height=82>"
         }
         document.write(pic);
       </script>
```

I think this is usable and what the person answered below meant, right?

Comment: Where is the code you have now? In what language is it written? What languages are you able to use at your hosting provider?

Comment: Is your "private start page" already in PHP? And/or already using jQuery? And are you comfortable hacking some code into either language? I.e.does "no programming skills" also mean you wouldn't know how to include a jquery plugin in to your website and configure it a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript. When the page loads, just check the date using new Date(), and if it matches with the specific user, just change the src attribute of the image.

Comment: Or use a serverside language to get the correct date... Javascript uses the date set on the client...

Comment: Yeah, actually that is better option. But as OP has said, OP don't have any programming skill, I think it's just html pages, there is no serverside scripting. So I suggested to use local checking.

Comment: Without the OP telling you this, you should not assume to know his setup. With no programming skill, OP won't be able to use your answer as a solution as well..

Comment: I think a JS solution is preferable for exactly the "Date on the client" reason. You want to wish someone happy birthday in the timezone they are in, not in a timezone possibly halfway round the world where your server is hosted.